# JavaScript file looks OK to me but getting a syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, unexpected-token

When I run my coffeescript test application I get this error"

```
2018-12-06 02:19:24,681 <NodeTest> [ERROR] [MainThread] node_test.run - NodeJS test for Node v7.9.0 did not pass. Exit status: 1
Std Out: 
Std Error: /opt/node_js/conf.js:25
            osVersion: 'MyOS 1.10.1.21
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This is the contents of `conf.js`:

```
const require('https');
module.exports = {
  // Endpoint
  endpoint: 'https://123.456.789.876',

  // creds
  access: 'accessblablabla',
  secret: 'secret blablabla',

  // Other options
  s3BucketEndpoint: false,
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  httpOptions: {
    agent: new https.Agent({ca: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'})
  },

  // OS version
  myOsVersion: 'MyOS 1.10.1.21'
}
```

I can't understand why `myOsVersion: '%s` is any different compared with anything else in the file. Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by the %s?  I pasted this into a node repl and it didn't complain.  The naked `require` is suspect (and probably not doing anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the space in the string.

As with @phix's comment, if I manually create the file there is no issue. I have a Python application which generates it. Perhaps it's including some hidden character or something.

Anyway, I only need the version number from the string so edited my Python code to look like this:

```
version = std_out.split()[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not use MacOS at all but from my view, I think you should declare:

```
const https = require('https');
```

At the top of your code, because I see you use the instance of this (the *new* keyword). Hope this can help you a bit!

Comment: side note: not related to MacOS at all